# 'Could not determine an IDataView type for member features' when call MakePredictionFunction

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm trying to make prediction function using new Microsoft.ML 0.6.0

When i call "model.AsDynamic.MakePredictionFunction", I receive

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView
>   type for member features'".

Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers;
using Microsoft.ML.StaticPipe;

namespace MachineLearning
{
    class MLTest
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var env = new LocalEnvironment();
            var reader = TextLoader.CreateReader(env, ctx => (label: ctx.LoadBool(0), features: ctx.LoadFloat(1, 3)));
            var traindata = reader.Read(new MultiFileSource("train.txt"));
            var bctx = new BinaryClassificationContext(env);
            var est = reader.MakeNewEstimator()
                .Append(x => (x.label, prediction: bctx.Trainers.Sdca(x.label, x.features.Normalize())));
            var model = est.Fit(traindata);

            //FAILS: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView type for member features'
            var predictionFunct = model.AsDynamic.MakePredictionFunction<Issue, Prediction>(env);

        }

        public class Issue
        {
            public float label;
            public Vector<float> features; //what is wrong?
        }

        public class Prediction
        {
            [ColumnName("prediction.predictedLabel")]
            public bool PredictionLabel;

            [ColumnName("prediction.probability")]
            public float Probability;

            [ColumnName("prediction.score")]
            public float Score;
        }
    }
}
```

File train.txt contains:

```
1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   0   0   1
1   0   1   1
0   1   1   1
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   0
0   1   0   0
```

It looks like error is in class "Issue", but what exactly is wrong? Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong here, but TextLoader.CreateReader should define the schema of your input and not featurized columns yet. I believe that should be done in the reader.MakeNewEstimator().Append() method. If this is to be true then your Issue class should also be a representation of your input schema. Try making those adjustments and see how it likes that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying [schema comprehension to make a dataview and to read](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/SchemaComprehension.md#using-schema-comprehension-to-make-a-data-view-and-to-read-a-data-view). By using a primative array, you can use the columntype to set the size of the array.

(This is for the version .10 of ML.NET)

```
public class Issue
{
        public float label;
        public float[] features; //change this
}
```

[Using SchemaDefinition for run-time type mapping hints](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/SchemaComprehension.md#using-schema-comprehension-to-make-a-data-view-and-to-read-a-data-view)

```
var inputSchemaDefinition = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(Issue), SchemaDefinition.Direction.Both);
inputSchemaDefinition["features"].ColumnType = new VectorType(NumberType.R4, 4);
```

Then you would create the engine :

```
var predictionEngine = model.CreatePredictionEngine<InputSchema, Prediction>(model as IHostEnvironment, inputSchemaDefinition, outputSchemaDefinition);
```